# How do I launch Spyder-Notebook?

Tags: spyder

I've installed the spyder-notebook plugin via `conda install spyder-notebook -c spyder-ide` as per the instructions [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-notebook). How do I actually open a `.ipynb` file using the plugin? After launching Spyder, there are no options to launch the notebook, and if I simply open a `.ipynb` file, it opens the markup instead of a notebook.

[image]

(spyder=3.3.2, spyder-kernels=0.3.0 spyder-notebook=0.1.3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) The notebook is started automatically. To see it in the Spyder interface, you need to look for a tab called *Notebook* and click it.

Then to open a notebook you need to click on the Options menu of the Notebook pane (the one to its right with a cog icon) and press *Open*. In Spyder 4 we're going to simplify that by using the Open button of the main Spyder toolbar.

Comment: I'm doing the same thing right now and can't find the new tab after installing; spyder==3.3.2; spyder-kernels==0.3.0; spyder-notebook==0.1.3; spyder-reports==0.1.1

Comment: There's a little incompatibility between our latest stable release (3.3.2) and Spyder-notebook that will be fixed in the next release of Spyder-notebook.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a Notebook tab (I added screenshot to original post). Is there a setting I need to toggle or is there some sort of issue with my install? (spyder=3.3.2, spyder-kernels=0.3.0 spyder-notebook=0.1.3)

Comment: @dkv, please see my comment above yours. The solution for now is to downgrade Spyder to 3.3.1 or wait until `spyder-notebook` **0.1.4** is released.

Comment: If you don't see the Notebook tab, read the other answer written by @apro2929. The tab is actually not up top like we'd expect, but at the **bottom of the Editor window** next to the Editor tab

Answer (score 3):

If the notebook launches in the spyder console [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hm5nc.png) and you cant find you can go to View > panes > uncheck then check notebook and that did the trick for me