# Is Spyder-Notebook available for Spyder-4?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, spyder

I've downloaded spyder-notebook using anaconda as shown below but cannot find any way to open up a notebook in spyder after doing so. I've looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53768250/how-do-i-launch-spyder-notebook) and it does not help. The only thing I can think of is that spyder-notebooks might not compatible with spyder 4 yet.

`conda install spyder-notebook -c spyder-ide`

Answer (score 1):

i have used it and you have to go to the toolbar and in view there is an option called "panes" and if you installed the notebook at the end of it appears an option as "Notebook" you just have to select it and thats it.