# How to open .ipynb file in Spyder?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, spyder

without using iSpyder DOS shell commands, how can an .ipynb (Jupyter Notebook) be opened directly into Spyder on Windows? Even the online Jupyter Notebook site prompts for a relative directory path where the file is stored.

- Why isn't there something that just loads the Notebook how it's supposed to look without typing a bunch of directory commands,
- and why does Spyder's RUN button become greyed out when it loads the .ipynb file?
- I have no idea what the .ipynb file format is compared to regular .py files

Opening lines of the .ipynb when loaded in Spyder are:

```
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 1,
   "metadata": {
    "ExecuteTime": {
```

This does not look like python code whatsoever

Comment: You will have to convert .ipynb to .py in order to open it in Spyder

Comment: Spyder already opens the .ipynb, but it's completely unintelligible. how to convert to .py then

Comment: Jupyter\iPython notebooks are stored in JSON format which is what you are seeing here

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may check out https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-notebook

Once you install this, you can open native .ipynb files in spyder

From the website:

> Spyder plugin to use Jupyter notebooks inside Spyder. Currently it
> supports basic functionality such as creating new notebooks, opening
> any notebook in your filesystem and saving notebooks at any location.
>
> You can also use Spyder's file switcher to easily switch between
> notebooks and open an IPython console connected to the kernel of a
> notebook to inspect its variables in the Variable Explorer.

Comment: from the question, can't you tell that I already have Spyder installed

Comment: This is a plugin for spyder, not spyder itself.

Comment: ok sorry for that. i installed spyder notebook, but nothing has changed when I open the file. the Run button is still grey. Am i supposed to import the spyder-notebook package or something

Comment: I think this should help: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53768250/how-do-i-launch-spyder-notebook#:~:text=To%20see%20it%20in%20the,cog%20icon)%20and%20press%20Open.

Comment: I don't see a tab called notebook in Spyder

Comment: There seems to be a discussion about that here: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-notebook/issues/146

TL;DR:
1.
In some cases when changing in Spyder View > Windows Layout to different view, notebook addon is unticked in Panes (so it dissaper from Spyder Windows)
When ticked again it land in land in the same windows as variable explorer (upper right window in spyder layout) not in the editor window (I am not treating this as bug but it may be confusing for some users, so I am writing it down here)

2.
if you do not see the notebook tab then try selecting View > Panes > Notebooks

Comment: I found the Notebook tab, it's at the bottom of the Editor pane, not up top

Comment: @pigeon_the_programmer +1; it has worked for me

Answer (score 8):

The jupyter notebook plugin currently works with Spyder 4.2.5 version and will not work with Spyder 5.X versions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spyder-5.x and therefore cannot use the Spyder-notebook plugin (see the other answers), an alternative is to export the .ipynb from Jupyter as an executable .py script first, then open the .py script in Spyder.

`Jupyter->Files->Save and Export Notebook as->Executable script`

The .py script produced preserves the ipython cells, using the

```
# In[<cell name or number>]:
```

syntax, for dividing the code into cells.

In Spyder, you can then `right-click` on the cell, and select `Run cell` to execute it in the Spyder console.

Beware, that *all* the cells (Code, Markdown, and Raw) are saved in the .py script. You may need to add `'''block quotes'''` around your Markdown and Raw cells, to prevent SyntaxErrors when running the .py script file.

Comment: Is there a way to add cells with this method?

Answer (score 1):

[Jupyter Notebook plugin](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-notebook#spyder-notebook-plugin) works on Spyder 5.4.0. Tested with plugin 0.4.0 of Sept 2022.

After installing the package using Conda, nothing seems to have changed and opening a Jupyter files just opens a text file, without interpreting any markdown inside, like it does without the plugin.

However there is now a tab row at the bottom of the editor:

[image]

You must switch to `Notebook` in order to work with Jupyter files. Use the double burger icon at top-right corner to open a file. Then you can execute the loaded file.

I noted some errors and differences in graphic outputs, but as the interface is really different from Spyder interface, I just copied the code into a regular Python file to get rid of Jupyter format dependency and I didn't dig further.

There is a warning [on the site](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-notebook/releases): *Spyder's standalone installer does not allow you to add plugins*. I don't know what it means, nor what does mean this other indication:

*At the moment it is not possible to use this plugin with the Spyder installers for Windows and macOS. We're working to make that a reality in the future.*

As I mentioned, the plugin was installed using Conda, in the environment used by Spyder, which is selected in the preferences, under `Python Interpreter`.

Comment: I am on 5.4.3 and I do see the tab.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to add cells with this method? – hulio_entredas

I've not had to myself, but I think this answers your question.

*Creating and Running Cells
Similar to Jupyter notebook, Spyder IDE allows you to create cells. To create a cell, simply put #%% in the script. Each #%% will signal generation of a new cell. To run a cell, press shift+enter while in focus of a cell. If you want to run only part of a script, you can do it by drag-selecting the part and pressing F9.*

From: [https://tellurium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/walkthrough.html#:~:text=and%20libRoadRunner%20Tutorial.-,Creating%20and%20Running%20Cells,in%20focus%20of%20a%20cell.](https://tellurium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/walkthrough.html#:%7E:text=and%20libRoadRunner%20Tutorial.-,Creating%20and%20Running%20Cells,in%20focus%20of%20a%20cell)